# C++11 experiments, why can't I use some of the features?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm currently overviewing the new features of C++11 and for currently ununderstood reasons, some of them does not compile. I use gcc version 4.6.0 20100703 (experimental) (GCC) so according to the GNU GCC FAQ, all features I tried are [supported](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/cxx0x_status.html) . I tried to compile with both of std=c++0x and std=gnu++0x flags.

### Non member begin() & end()

For instance, I wan't to use non member begin() and end(), in piece of code like :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;
int main ( ) {
    map < string, string > alias;
    alias.insert ( pair < string, string > ( "ll", "ls -al" ) );
    // ... Other inserts

    auto it = begin(alias);
    while ( it != end(alias) ) {
        //...
    }
```

And I get,

```
nonMemberBeginEnd//main.cc:15:24: error: ‘begin’ was not declared in this scope
nonMemberBeginEnd//main.cc:15:24: error: unable to deduce ‘auto’ from ‘<expression error>’ // Ok, this one is normal.
nonMemberBeginEnd//main.cc:16:26: error: ‘end’ was not declared in this scope
```

Do I need to include special headers ?

### For range

My second (and last) question is weirder because It cannot depend on black magic hidden header that I might had not included.

The following code :

```
for ( auto kv : alias )
    cout << kv.first << " ~ " << kv.second << endl;
```

Give me the following errors :

```
rangeFor/main.cc:15:17: error: expected initializer before ‘:’ token
```

I hope my questions are not off topic or too rookie for you guys and you'll help me find out what's wrong :D

Comment: Your GCC build is marked as experimental, so it's a snapshot of 4.6. The documentation you linked is about the 4.6 *release*, and is thus not representative of what you have.

Comment: ^^^ That exactly. Works fine with GCC 4.6.1 here.

Comment: Wow well spoted... I'll try to get the release version. :D

Comment: As a funny anecdote, you can even combine this with lambda, reaching entirely new levels of obfuscation, even for C++ standards: `for(auto& x : my_array)[&x](){x*=x;}();`. It's stunning (and scary at the same time) that you can write code like this and it actually works.  :-)

Comment: "Moreover you're wrong because the non-member begin() and end() are automatically included when using <map>, <array>, etc." Not in a guaranteed fashion, maybe on your implementation. In general, it's unspecified whether or not standard headers include other standard headers, and in C++11 all `<map>` (for example) is required to include is `<initializer_list>`. Any inclusion of `<iterator>` is purely by chance.

Comment: @GMan : Not true; the FDIS, §24.6.5/1 explicitly says "*In addition to being available via inclusion of the `<iterator>` header, the function templates in 24.6.5 are available when any of the following headers are included: `<array>`, `<deque>`, `<forward_list>`, `<list>`, `<map>`, `<regex>`, `<set>`, `<string>`, `<unordered_map>`, `<unordered_set>`, and `<vector>`.*" (§24.6.5 defines the function templates for `std::begin` and `std::end`)

Comment: @ildjarn: Good to know, thanks. It's a bit silly not to put them in the `<map>` et. al. header synopsis as well, IMO, which is where we've been "trained" to see what headers are required to include others. Shame on me for not checking both ways, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works on gcc 4.6.1:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::map<std::string, std::string> alias = {{"key", "value"}};
    for (auto kv: alias)
        std::cout << kv.first << " ~ " << kv.second << std::endl;

    auto it = begin(alias);
    while (it != end(alias) ) {
        std::cout << (*it).first << " ~ " << (*it).second << std::endl;
        it++;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And the result:

```
# /opt/gcc-4.6.1/bin/g++-4.6 --std=c++0x test.cc -o test && ./test
key ~ value
key ~ value
```